# Parabola - Definition as a locus of points

Tags: geometry, definition, conic-sections, locus

On Wikipedia, a parabola is defined as follows:

> A parabola is a set of points such that, for any point $P$ of the parabola, the distance $|\overline{PF}|$ to a fixed point $F$, the focus, is equal to the distance $|\overline{Pl}|$ to a fixed line $l$

Isn't this definition wrong since an empty set is a parabola according to it?

Is the following definition correct?

> For any set of points $S$, $S$ is a parabola if and only if
>   there exists a point $F$ and a line $l$ such that
>   $F$ isn't on $l$ and for any point $P$, $P$ is in $S$ if and only if $|\overline{PF}|=|\overline{Pl}|$.

Comment: The definition should involve the set of *all* points such that…

Comment: @avraham One description of a parabola involves a point (the focus) and a line (the directrix). **The focus does not lie on the directrix.** The parabola is the locus of points in that plane that are equidistant from both the directrix and the focus. (Cited from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola )

Answer (score 3):

Your criticism is justified. The definition should say, not that the parabola is *a* set of points such that…, but that it is *the* set of *all* points such that… (in other words, it's the *locus* of those points). On the other hand, that article says that “The focus does not lie on the directrix”.